# Field Collection alternative ? Need Sub fields searchable through Search API (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-search, drupal-field-collection

I am hoping to find an alternative to Field Collection module. The problem is that I want to search (I am using Search API + Views) the sub fields in the Field Collection.

As an example, If I have a Field Collection "Field", as `Research Paper`, with following fields:-

- Title of the Research
- PDF Document.

I can add as many `Research Papers` in my Page where I added the `Research Paper` as the content type.

Following are, for example, the typical Research Papers I added:-

- "Botany", "Finding a sustainable source of blah blah.pdf"
- "Economics", "Research on correlation of customer spending and weather conditions.pdf"
- "Mathematics", "Estimating Pi series within Rational numbers.pdf"

Now, comes the problem, if I made a Search Page through Search API by a view, and search "**sustainable source of blah blah**", how can I get the link to the 'Research Paper` entry of "Botany", "Finding a sustainable source of blah blah.pdf"?

I am using view and searching through "Fulltext search (exposed)".

Here is the view, just in case:

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'advanced_search';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'search_api_index_advanced_search_index';
$view->human_name = 'Advanced Search';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Advanced Search';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Search';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['autosubmit'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['autosubmit_hide'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Indexed Node: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'search_api_index_advanced_search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
/* Field: Indexed Node: The main body text » Summary */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['id'] = 'body_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['table'] = 'search_api_index_advanced_search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['field'] = 'body_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['max_length'] = '200';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['trim'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['empty'] = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vitae est id metus vestibulum mattis. Donec sed dictum sapien. Proin facilisis vehicula elit nec molestie. Nullam scelerisque, urna non venenatis mattis, dolor neque ultricies tellus, quis lacinia mi ligula id risus. Curabitur congue gravida quam. Maecenas et luctus dui. Aliquam erat volutpat ...';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['empty_zero'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['hide_alter_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['body_summary']['link_to_entity'] = 0;
/* Field: Document Category » Uploaded File » The file.: Title Text (indexed) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['id'] = 'field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['table'] = 'search_api_index_advanced_search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['field'] = 'field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_document_cat_field_field_document_file_field_file_image_title_text']['field_api_classes'] = 0;
/* Filter criterion: Search: Fulltext search */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['id'] = 'search_api_views_fulltext';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['table'] = 'search_api_index_advanced_search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['field'] = 'search_api_views_fulltext';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'search_api_views_fulltext_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['expose']['label'] = 'Search me';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['expose']['use_operator'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['expose']['operator'] = 'search_api_views_fulltext_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['expose']['identifier'] = 'search_api_views_fulltext';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['expose']['required'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['search_api_views_fulltext']['fields'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
  'body:value' => 'body:value',
  'field_document_cat_field:field_document:file:name' => 'field_document_cat_field:field_document:file:name',
  'field_document_cat_field:field_document:file:field_file_image_title_text' => 'field_document_cat_field:field_document:file:field_file_image_title_text',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'advanced-search';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [inline_entity_form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) or [multifield](https://drupal.org/project/multifield) modules.

related link : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/alternative-to-field-collection